# Partner with Facebook for 10+ years and app was erroneously deactivated - need assistance getting it reactivated

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I work for an online apparel company and we use Facebook login for our customers.  We've had this integration going for a long time now - probably about a decade or longer.

Last month, it looks like we got some automated emails stating 'When reviewing your app, we weren't able to find any Facebook integration or verify the permission use case that you provided during App Review'

As a a result of those emails being lost in the shuffle, the app has now been deactivated, by what appears to be a completely automated process.  We now have customers calling us saying they can no longer log in with Facebook.

I find it extremely disappointing that it's even possible that something like this can occur in an automated fashion for an app that has been live for so long and that has people using it every day.

If anyone can assist in helping us get reactivated, the app ID is 94490422409.

I tried to appeal, explaining that there must be some mistake since the integration has been working just fine for our customers for years, but it's been over a week and no response has been received.